# aws cli's response is not json format

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, iterm

When I authenticate in cognito using `aws cognito-idp admin-initiate-auth` with iterm, the response format is not json(like below).
And the key of value aren't shown, so I can't find which is access token.

Could you tell me how to change the response format to JSON?

command

```
aws cognito-idp admin-initiate-auth \
--user-pool-id poolId \
--client-id clientId \
--auth-flow ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH \
--auth-parameters USERNAME=test,PASSWORD=password \
--region us-east-2
```

response

```
AUTHENTICATIONRESULT    eyJraWQiOiJKYnJpK1VyWitNdkcwZUpjUnVpRXlQYkgxcGp6VEdxXC9SWHJkU2lUOVFmVT0iLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJjZjU5OWRiYi02OWI0LTRiYzUtYThjOC0yNTA0ZjYwZTk2NWMiLCJldmVudF9pZCI6ImM5MDliZjM3LWEzNTMtNDZlNS1hODc5LWJhMjU0YjEyNDhhMyIsInRva2VuX3VzZSI6ImFjY2VzcyIsInNjb3BlIjoiYXdzLmNvZ25pdG8uc2lnbmluLnVzZXIuYWRtaW4iLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE2MDYzOTQzMjEsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOlwvXC9jb2duaXRvLWlkcC51cy1lYXN0LTIuYW1hem9uYXdzLmNvbVwvdXMtZWFzdC0yXzdBSThjQlJyUiIsImV4cCI6MTYwNjM5NzkyMSwiaWF0IjoxNjA2Mzk0MzIxLCJqdGkiOiIzNzZiOWM3OC1iYjBiLTQ5YWEtYjM4Yi0xMzU2ZGExODk4NmUiLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiI2NnY1NHNpMmw1ZXN1bmNmdXJvam5mOW1iaiIsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoidGVzdCJ9.hscAES9pBnzXABJvf2eI1UufKUIXvLBHr-_D9_isl73ytLbeDnSH0-gUl9LSPHgeQVZcNOxshsWzuEYMCB7HCVGUPtUtSMBma6Fd3n84RGOnYw768Wc9EvurY82liSFakeIT_9dCdTrhVzgXhlbH4dhmdxljYvCpn1LPS21AdN008KzLY9XAiXHdDOi5VmORreQ5y_zqTmOIpXgMBgQhy_M8G-hWroQYSvU4cDciJ9XTFQjzKBnIbte846f0Ohpqy6PYgC55kiaaXECvCVl63g7gtSXwE-4tTfIo4aoG1UGNMXgPOa-AVzVYU-aIPNypZNt4z8k1ourWwRdMCZJFGA        3600    eyJraWQiOiJjZUgwVkhjSE1TN1wvWHB1M3RcL2FtNFwvRno2RzcwclUwcVVOOU5iVm5EdHc0PSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0.eyJzdWIiOiJjZjU5OWRiYi02OWI0LTRiYzUtYThjOC0yNTA0ZjYwZTk2NWMiLCJhdWQiOiI2NnY1NHNpMmw1ZXN1bmNmdXJvam5mOW1iaiIsImVtYWlsX3ZlcmlmaWVkIjp0cnVlLCJldmVudF9pZCI6ImM5MDliZjM3LWEzNTMtNDZlNS1hODc5LWJhMjU0YjEyNDhhMyIsInRva2VuX3VzZSI6ImlkIiwiYXV0aF90aW1lIjoxNjA2Mzk0MzIxLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczpcL1wvY29nbml0by1pZHAudXMtZWFzdC0yLmFtYXpvbmF3cy5jb21cL3VzLWVhc3QtMl83QUk4Y0JSclIiLCJjb2duaXRvOnVzZXJuYW1lIjoidGVzdCIsImV4cCI6MTYwNjM5NzkyMSwiaWF0IjoxNjA2Mzk0MzIxLCJlbWFpbCI6InluaXNoaW1vdG9Ad2Jjb21wYW55LmNvLmpwIn0.OrUW7rLAZ7w01o0ifn_5wsJkgZ8FFyWmlaeFLhZTh_iWKqsO0437rsZxjeAkfqK3wyruHSdL4ag_Z_epmbtdIoYlOHhikofIYEfbCKsvOQ-BY9Ik0IpDpGFhugYRQGY80szfzILbLFXhzWYwbRkYqBD3-BJt9Xv9xSupuVIW1NcygtELF7JEyWx0UcojIBxvtbJmibFfmkqCJhHhPna2gTB-dnPhmopLXwIEocyeRMlNCC8PByBRvUgUDgffq_KaWzVY8yANBc0COHVg0_KgX_KQSU2fZb9NrcX1sYbwtdn3BX5MN0bucoeey7LGQ_9ECH8DeVsb6oCqECK9:
AUTHENTICATIONRESULT    eyJraWQiOiJKYnJpK1VyWitNdkcwZUpjUnVpRXlQYkgxcGp6VEdxXC9SWHJkU2lUOVFmVT0iLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJjZjU5OWRiYi02OWI0LTRiYzUtYThjOC0yNTA0ZjYwZTk2NWMiLCJldmVudF9pZCI6ImM5MDliZjM3LWEzNTMtNDZlNS1hODc5LWJhMjU0YjEyNDhhMyIsInRva2VuXVzZSI6ImFjY2VzcyIsInNjb3BlIjoiYXdzLmNvZ25pdG8uc2lnbmluLnVzZXIuYWRtaW4iLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE2MDYzOTQzMjEsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOlwvXC9jb2duaXRvLWlkcC51cy1lYXN0LTIuYW1hem9uYXdzLmNvbVwvdXMtZWFzdC0yXzdBSThjQlJyUiIsImV4cCI6MTYwNjM5NzkyMSwiaWF0IjoxNjA2Mzk0MzIxLCJqdGkiOiIzNzZiOWM3OC1iYjBiLTQ5YWEtYjM4Yi0xMzU2ZGExODk4NmUiLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiI2NnY1NHNpMmw1ZXN1bmNmdXJvam5mOW1iaiIsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoidGVzdCJ9.hscAES9pBnzXABJvf2eI1UufKUIXvLBHr-_D9_isl73ytLbeDnSH0-gUl9LSPHgeQVZcNOxshsWzuEYMCB7HCVGUPtUtSMBma6Fd3n84RGOnYw768Wc9EvurY82liSFakeIT_9dCdTrhVzgXhlbH4dhmdxljYvCpn1LPS21AdN008KzLY9XAiXHdDOi5VmORreQ5y_zqTmOIpXgMBgQhy_M8G-hWroQYSvU4cDciJ9XTFQjzKBnIbte846f0Ohpqy6PYgC55kiaaXECvCVl63g7gtSXwE-4tTfIo4aoG1UGNMXgPOa-AVzVYU-aIPNypZNt4z8k1ourWwRdMCZJFGA        3600    eyJraWQiOiJjZUgwVkhjSE1TN1wvWHB1M3RcL2FtNFwvRno2RzcwclUwcVVOOU5iVm5EdHc0PSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0.eyJzdWIiOiJjZjU5OWRiYi02OWI0LTRiYzUtYThjOC0yNTA0ZjYwZTk2NWMiLCJhdWQiOiI2NnY1NHNpMmw1ZXN1bmNmdXJvam5mOW1iaiIsImVtYWlsX3ZlcmlmaWVkIjp0cnVlLCJldmVudF9pZCI6ImM5MDliZjM3LWEzNTMtNDZlNS1hODc5LWJhMjU0YjEyNDhhMyIsInRva2VuX3VzZSI6ImlkIiwiYXV0aF90aW1lIjoxNjA2Mzk0MzIxLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczpcL1wvY29nbml0by1pZHAudXMtZWFzdC0yLmFtYXpvbmF3cy5jb21cL3VzLWVhc3QtMl83QUk4Y0JSclIiLCJjb2duaXRvOnVzZXJuYW1lIjoidGVzdCIsImV4cCI6MTYwNjM5NzkyMSwiaWF0IjoxNjA2Mzk0MzIxLCJlbWFpbCI6InluaXNoaW1vdG9Ad2Jjb21wYW55LmNvLmpwIn0.OrUW7rLAZ7w01o0ifn_5wsJkgZ8FFyWmlaeFLhZTh_iWKqsO0437rsZxjeAkfqK3wyruHSdL4ag_Z_epmbtdIoYlOHhikofIYEfbCKsvOQ-BY9Ik0IpDpGFhugYRQGY80szfzILbLFXhzWYwbRkYqBD3-BJt9Xv9xSupuVIW1NcygtELF7JEyWx0UcojIBxvtbJmibFfmkqCJhHhPna2gTB-dnPhmopLXwIEocyeRMlNCC8PByBRvUgUDgffq_KaWzVY8yANBc0COHVg0_KgX_KQSU2fZb9NrcX1sYbwtdn3BX5MN0bucoeey7LGQ_9ECH8DeVsb6oCqECK9W24azw  eyJjdHkiOiJKV1QiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIiwiYWxnIjoiUlNBLU9BRVAifQ.fuLU8NapfiaaSFe-a6L60WKYv9lAVlG8lpYFrRrDBCLOY-MDf:...skipping...
AUTHENTICATIONRESULT    eyJraWQiOiJKYnJpK1VyWitNdkcwZUpjUnVpRXlQYkgxcGp6VEdxXC9SWHJkU2lUOVFmVT0iLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.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.hscAES9pBnzXABJvf2eI1UufKUIXvLBHr-_D9_isl73ytLbeDnSH0-gUl9LSPHgeQVZcNOxshsWzuEYMCB7HCVGUPtUtSMBma6Fd3n84RGOnYw768Wc9EvurY82liSFakeIT_9dCdTrhVzgXhlbH4dhmdxljYvCpn1LPS21AdN008KzLY9XAiXHdDOi5VmORreQ5y_zqTmOIpXgMBgQhy_M8G-hWroQYSvU4cDciJ9XTFQjzKBnIbte846f0Ohpqy6PYgC55kiaaXECvCVl63g7gtSXwE-4tTfIo4aoG1UGNMXgPOa-AVzVYU-aIPNypZNt4z8k1ourWwRdMCZJFGA        3600    eyJraWQiOiJjZUgwVkhjSE1TN1wvWHB1M3RcL2FtNFwvRno2RzcwclUwcVVOOU5iVm5EdHc0PSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0.eyJzdWIiOiJjZjU5OWRiYi02OWI0LTRiYzUtYThjOC0yNTA0ZjYwZTk2NWMiLCJhdWQiOiI2NnY1NHNpMmw1ZXN1bmNmdXJvam5mOW1iaiIsImVtYWlsX3ZlcmlmaWVkIjp0cnVlLCJldmVudF9pZCI6ImM5MDliZjM3LWEzNTMtNDZlNS1hODc5LWJhMjU0YjEyNDhhMyIsInRva2VuX3VzZSI6ImlkIiwiYXV0aF90aW1lIjoxNjA2Mzk0MzIxLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczpcL1wvY29nbml0by1pZHAudXMtZWFzdC0yLmFtYXpvbmF3cy5jb21cL3VzLWVhc3QtMl83QUk4Y0JSclIiLCJjb2duaXRvOnVzZXJuYW1lIjoidGVzdCIsImV4cCI6MTYwNjM5NzkyMSwiaWF0IjoxNjA2Mzk0MzIxLCJlbWFpbCI6InluaXNoaW1vdG9Ad2Jjb21wYW55LmNvLmpwIn0.OrUW7rLAZ7w01o0ifn_5wsJkgZ8FFyWmlaeFLhZTh_iWKqsO0437rsZxjeAkfqK3wyruHSdL4ag_Z_epmbtdIoYlOHhikofIYEfbCKsvOQ-BY9Ik0IpDpGFhugYRQGY80szfzILbLFXhzWYwbRkYqBD3-BJt9Xv9xSupuVIW1NcygtELF7JEyWx0UcojIBxvtbJmibFfmkqCJhHhPna2gTB-dnPhmopLXwIEocyeRMlNCC8PByBRvUgUDgffq_KaWzVY8yANBc0COHVg0_KgX_KQSU2fZb9NrcX1sYbwtdn3BX5MN0bucoeey7LGQ_9ECH8DeVsb6oCqECK9W24azw  eyJjdHkiOiJKV1QiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIiwiYWxnIjoiUlNBLU9BRVAifQ.fuLU8NapfiaaSFe-a6L60WKYv9lAVlG8lpYFrRrDBCLOY-MDfbLCYOsGxmzqe2qMwxSg1voMzfz8Y60n9fwluAMo3PB_eq8oSGxLYTlfRSC-rLkVlqzjn5a63j_eVQJEv9pqt8CVC5vmIy9eQmgq8S_xSebQtLem4fisgMqOngy9NQKh3DwCp7HzLoMPRaN-VDufthiTypy7FBozRp1y3ALL6bF8vMQCfZo1rfYV5ccz88GJLe_CNR5fyQWcsfDZlE7G0c-pp93Kk-05DJwNzFldA7SHA58YxqgU8lgj64_vdTvXiewYVn0T4DwauaZRK0l59l582eO3zGJAL0Zfcw.lOV7vpwc-7Iaro4p.RyIzGzu0Wds4R933m4fafIAcdKSPvyLzqtJgDrGoUqG-BkfM7DwGddSUzQYqb6KbV_pBx-nnMR9I99eqlq-lGYXZjzpMJoNBa15MsfUoQUlhxHFVyDjdtaupC6lcxwcbyDVRLyG9SYBXBV9cRv7_hgl-2H90S6_qBqMmL-xMUV23il8cMWGyjdUKXtGBvuFgX_zFVYakFE1tzckzf1tLf43vsOEPzKjCOWcJzuHnS5amvMWQff_IRr-3aPOrSVg-zncOcprUyCCkK8Js8o3B00HMDI2b_XB4zoGCfx5YUvAxWph8_Mou-lugy3E7c4FdezOr0jjhrrnFmW-4L3xIVvI_K4ucZ0CBSWeM_xUyNxfkHtWgRol2aw66kS7OFHXBIWW76W8BgQP0RALmEnvmmLdaGrJSUtQ5fx0ghrFmU2gY5GvvGtnqNq9FzJAlFdcKku1p33Nma8lugdMgRq97Yj2L8ox5X47c7O4_MqRY3KHYSTyUYg9WGSKyaZ9MXg1FWtORKJQK6CEtnUBgPXKRRwD9o8q5NI_E2xzp0m1Oo2K48iFEcY706DJrMd7nyzuMg0cQppnmIBan30QfRtRZD2Gz0LZOAfIrBmqUntCVB4BkxPD5U1qzOugKr6ZbyxlcfUtotCr5ZeBE5kKuHdobrPhSistrzpSnB1whldEEkK6f62ut91wV2pKqTVk7m1IHo7ZcKEcwWBXcjaalQ7U450bUO9Rpyv09wT2JTvLrtP3FDMLf57xQyVykQoDAXTGLx_0m5ZrtVaTJ6kETEKhgOwz2ulaI6olclu_J_bU0U5iC-9a1pga2x8aw-0NiDGRL738oaZIPwTDro0z4m66thIChWLib4u-BGguypKIE_8Txbes92pWDJTqf5aqzQCQqobUTb94mcGK3f3F8Gws8oIvW9Bz1SbCoZsfF0v4ijFryCS0GSHUqAl_6kP-QDUqZT1K1_BCZOoNRJHqqgGpc4uEgJUOmusns8cA8bCDa5_M4jNVhyP8XZDkOtbLdV7VBVF87VZ2nGzxYIXgvXv5HbtGTOfJXV-0OJV7X3IOIni5Xv9_wK0kC_rfH6dKHu_qiJFGu_1VhMLEv4kfPGCvsHcTw10yLb0rQhn49lstSp432gBSc96iVCHTEUpIZvKZke8cpRPWkPwYdz3S5QN06u5Qm2-xutCdlS1R2nqwTJlMAd5vgrCAcuhQOil9sJzB3QygCZdkjzLjVn7WgyGg2O1RDjQLLHvHGWPWvfOAcxfrZ0edaB6hfIwq7q_-BhOKgvA.Ig_CXUVGKB1Y00szRUiI3Q        Bearer
```

I don't know that is the cause... I can't get access-token from the resopnse using query.

```
aws cognito-idp admin-initiate-auth \
--user-pool-id poolId \
--client-id clientId \
--auth-flow ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH \
--auth-parameters USERNAME=test,PASSWORD=password \
--region us-east-2 \
--query "AuthorizationResult.AccessToken"

None
```

Comment: You have gotten them access_token, id_token, and refresh_token. They are base64 based encode format. If you parse each encode string, in JavaScript can use atob, you will get the full data in json format

Comment: Something like var tokenobj = JSON.parse(atob("eyJraWQiOiJKYnJpK1VyWitNdkcw......")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have the `output` set to `text` in your `config` file or somewhere else: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output.html

If you want to keep it that way you can always run the specific cli command with `--output json` as an additional argument.

Comment: This is exactly what I want, and worked well. Thank you.